# npm package.json aliases like webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

i am trying to alias a module however i am not sure how to do that with package.json

in webpack you would do something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'pixi.js': 'pixi.js-legacy'
    }
  }
};
```

But what is the equivalent without webpack?

Comment: I have two packages `ajs` and `bjs`. One installs using `npm i ajs` and `npm i bjs`. I wish to install `bjs` when I run `npm i ajs`. Is it possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72554667/install-package-x-when-a-request-for-package-y-installation-is-made

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a npm package for this: [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias).

After installing it you can add your aliases to the package.json, like so:

```
"_moduleAliases": {
  "@root"      : ".", // Application's root
  "@deep"      : "src/some/very/deep/directory/or/file",
  "@my_module" : "lib/some-file.js",
  "something"  : "src/foo", // Or without @. Actually, it could be any string
}
```

Make sure to add this line at the top of your app's main file:

```js
require('module-alias/register');
```

You should only use this in final products (and not packages you intend to publish in npm or use elsewhere) - it modifies the behavior of require.

Answer (score 24):

Since NPM [Version 6.9](https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/3) of March 2019 it is supported without installing any additional packages ([see the RFC](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/implemented/0001-package-aliases.md)):

```
npm i aliasName@npm:packageToInstall
```

⬇⬇⬇

```js
// package.json
"dependencies": {
    "aliasName": "npm:packageToInstall@^1.6.1"
}
```

The idea seems to be that `npm:` is a URI-like scheme in a *dependency version specifier*.

Usage:

```js
const alias = require( 'aliasName' );
```

Comment: I have two packages `ajs` and `bjs`. One installs using `npm i ajs` and `npm i bjs`. I wish to install `bjs` when I run `npm i ajs`. Is it possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72554667/install-package-x-when-a-request-for-package-y-installation-is-made

Comment: This solution is not friendly if using `yalc` for dev locally. `yalc` read `aliasName` while the published one is `packageToInstall`, which doesn't match. Now my fix is to manually modify the `name` in `package.json` when doing `yalc publish`, to match the `aliasName`.